# Problem with biblatex-chicago package

Tags: biblatex-chicago

I have problem with biblatex-chicago package. When the article does not have a volume number, the reference generated has a missing space before number page. I provide a MWE as below. Please help me! I have tried for a long time, but did not find a solution.

```
\documentclass[american]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel,csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber,authordate]{biblatex-chicago}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
  @ARTICLE{adams1887,
    author = {Adams, Henry Carter},
    title = {Relation of the State to Industrial Action},
    journaltitle = {Publications of the American Economic Association},
    date = {1887},
    volume = {1},
    number = {6},
    pages = {7--85}
    }  
@article{chan1999hukou,
  title={The Hukou System and Rural-urban Migration in China: Processes and Changes},
  author={Chan, Kam Wing and Zhang, Li},
  journal={China Quarterly},
  volume={160},
  pages={818--855},
  year={1999},
  publisher={Cambridge University Press}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
Example.
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Dai. I knew this post, but his answer would change the citation style of articles with issue numbers where there is an extra comma after volume number.

Comment: In fact you copy the question almost exactly without reference, that's really unhelpful and not in accordance with the license content on this site is made available under (https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/licensing).

Comment: I updated the answer in the linked question.